# How to get AM/PM from a datetime in PHP

Tags: php, date, formatting

I have a date time in a variable. My format is `08/04/2010 22:15:00`. I want to display this like `10.15 PM`. How to do this in PHP?

Comment: Similar: [How to convert the time from AM/PM to 24 hour format in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16955209/55075)

Answer (score 207, accepted):

You need to convert it to a UNIX timestamp (using [strtotime](http://www.php.net/strtotime)) and then back into the format you require using the [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

For example:

```
$currentDateTime = '08/04/2010 22:15:00';
$newDateTime = date('h:i A', strtotime($currentDateTime));
```

Answer (score 26):

```
$dateString = '08/04/2010 22:15:00';
$dateObject = new DateTime($dateString);
echo $dateObject->format('h:i A');
```

Comment: It works pretty fine!

Answer (score 20):

Use `strtotime()` to make the date a UNIX timestamp.

For output, check out the various options of [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
$timestamp = strtotime("08/04/2010 22:15:00");
date("h.i A", $timestamp);
```

Comment: Not too sure about the uppercase "H" in the date call (odd to have a 24hr with the AM/PM). Yes, I'm quibbling as you've beaten me to it. Again. :-)

Answer (score 16):

```
<?php 
$dateTime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata')); 
echo $dateTime->format("d/m/y  H:i A"); 
?>
```

You can use this to display the date like this

```
22/06/15 10:46 AM
```

Comment: H:i A should be lower case h

Answer (score 11):

Like this:

```
$date = '08/04/2010 22:15:00';
echo date('h:i A', strtotime($date));
```

**Result:**

```
10:15 PM
```

**More Info:**

- [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
- [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 7):

for flexibility with different formats, use:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i:s', '08/04/2010 22:15:00');
echo $dt->format('g:i A')
```

Check the [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for additional format options.

Answer (score 7):

PHP Code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$currentDateTime=date('m/d/Y H:i:s');
$newDateTime = date('h:i A', strtotime($currentDateTime));
echo $newDateTime;
```

Output: 05:03 PM

Answer (score 6):

```
$currentDateTime = $row['date'];
echo $newDateTime = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', strtotime($currentDateTime));
```

Answer (score 4):

Perfect answer for AM/PM live time solution

```
<?php echo date('h:i A', time())?>
```

Comment: Super Answer. I dont know why this answer only get 2 upvotes. this is the perfect solution

Comment: Its a good and short answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just simply right A

```
{{ date('h:i A', strtotime($varname->created_at))}}
```

Answer (score 1):

For (PHP >= 5.2.0):

You can use DateTime class. However you might need to change your date format. Didn't try yours.
The following date format will work for sure: `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS`

```
$date = new DateTime("2010-04-08 22:15:00");
echo $date->format("g"). '.' .$date->format("i"). ' ' .$date->format("A");

//output
//10.15 PM
```

However, in my opinion, using `.` as a separator for `10.15` is not recommended because your users might be confused either this is a decimal number or time format. The most common way is to use `10:15 PM`

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy. Assuming you have a field(dateposted) with the type "timestamp"  in your database table already queried and you want to display it, have it formated and also have the **AM/PM**, all you need do is shown below.

```
     <?php
     echo date("F j, Y h:m:s A" ,strtotime($row_rshearing['dateposted'])); 


    ?>
```

Note: Your **OUTPUT** should look some what like this depending on the date posted

**May 21, 2014 03:05:27 PM**