# How to convert the time from AM/PM to 24 hour format in PHP?

Tags: php, string, date

For example, I have a time in this format:

```
eg. 

09:15 AM
04:25 PM
11:25 AM
```

How do I convert it to :

```
09:15
16:25
23:25
```

Currently my code is :

```
$format_time = str_replace(" AM", "", $time, $count);
if ($count === 0){
    $format_time = strstr($time, ' PM', true);
    $format_time = ......
}
```

However, it seems there are some easier and more elegant way to do this?

```
$time = '23:45'; 
echo date('g:i a', strtotime($time));
```

How do I fit the above sample in my case? Thanks.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Try with this

```
echo date("G:i", strtotime($time));
```

or you can try like this also

```
echo date("H:i", strtotime("04:25 PM"));
```

Comment: `G` - 24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros - 0 through 23; `H` - 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros - 00 through 23

Answer (score 11):

If you use a Datetime format see http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

You can do this :

```
$date = new \DateTime();
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
#output: 2012-03-24 17:45:12

echo date_format($date, 'G:ia');
#output: 05:45pm
```

Comment: Not relevant to question. Your answer is just opposite of it, but helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

PHP 5.3+ solution.

```
$new_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', '01:00 PM');
$time_24 = $new_time->format('H:i:s');
```

> Output: 13:00:00

Works great when formatting of date is required. Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11435664/4311336) Answer for details.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this for 24 hour to 12 hour:

```
echo date("h:i", strtotime($time));
```

And for vice versa:

```
echo date("H:i", strtotime($time));
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `Carbon`

```
 $time = '09:15 PM';
 $s=Carbon::parse($time);
 echo $military_time =$s->format('G:i');
```

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 2):

```
$Hour1 = "09:00 am";
$Hour =  date("H:i", strtotime($Hour1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$s = '07:05:45PM';
$tarr = explode(':', $s);
if(strpos( $s, 'AM') === false && $tarr[0] !== '12'){
    $tarr[0] = $tarr[0] + 12;
}elseif(strpos( $s, 'PM') === false && $tarr[0] == '12'){
    $tarr[0] = '00';
}
echo preg_replace("/[^0-9 :]/", '', implode(':', $tarr));
```

Comment: I would suggest you to add additional details on what your approach is solving and how. Dumping lines of code without any additional information can become more confusing than helpful if the person asking the question doesn't fully understand the way the problem was solved. It's always a good idea to add a brief description

Comment: You can use this code for convert 12 hour time to 24 hour time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = '09:15 AM';

$chunks = explode(':', $time);
if (strpos( $time, 'AM') === false && $chunks[0] !== '12') {
    $chunks[0] = $chunks[0] + 12;
} else if (strpos( $time, 'PM') === false && $chunks[0] == '12') {
    $chunks[0] = '00';
}

echo preg_replace('/\s[A-Z]+/s', '', implode(':', $chunks));
```

Answer (score -1):

We Can Create AM/PM by Carbon Laravel

```
Carbon::parse('your Value')->format('g:i A');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).