# Convert army time to regular time (AM/PM) in PHP

Tags: php, time

Is there a way to convert army time (such as 23:00) to regular time with the AM/PM expression?

Comment: I think "Army time" is more popularly known as the "[24 hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock)" `:-p`

Comment: $time24 = '23:00';
$dt = new DateTime($time24);
echo $dt->format('h:i A');

Comment: @marabutt - I think you have to have a minimum of 1K rep here before you're allowed to swear at posters.

Comment: Duplicate of: [How to convert the time from AM/PM to 24 hour format in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16955209/55075)

Comment: try this from loop: echo date("g:i a", strtotime($result['hourOpeningHour']))

Answer (score 20):

Just pass your time to the [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function like this:

```
$time_in_12_hour_format = date("g:i a", strtotime("23:00"));
echo $time_in_12_hour_format;
```

Comment: This is the one you're looking for my friends.

Answer (score 8):

Use *[date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)*:

```
$army_time_str = "23:00";
$regular_time_str = date( 'g:i A', strtotime( $army_time_str ) );
echo $regular_time_str;
```

Comment: great it works..

Answer (score 3):

The input $time is in the form of 'XXXX' (e.g. '0000', '0001',...,'2300'). I couldn't find a function for this, so I wrote the following.

```
function convert_army_to_regular($time) {
    $hours = substr($time, 0, 2);
    $minutes = substr($time, 2, 2);

    if ($hours > 12) {
        $hours = $hours - 12;
        $ampm = 'PM';
    } else {
        if ($hours != 11) {
            $hours = substr($hours, 1, 1);
        }
        $ampm = 'AM';
    }
    return $hours . ':' . $minutes . $ampm;
}
```

Comment: It's probably better to convert the time to a unix timestamp, and then render using `date` - which is very flexible. Still, +1.

Comment: The obvious answer is to convert it to a unix timestamp or a DateTime object, and then use date() or the DateTime format() method... so much cleaner and easier