# Time difference calculate late - PHP

Tags: php, time

what I want to do is calculate the `late`in these time:

1. Time-in  = **22:00**  (10:00 PM)
2. Time-out = **1:30** (1:30 AM)

The output should be **3:30** i want to get this output

How can I calculate the difference and what built-in function in `php` should be used to achieved this? Can someone give me a clue?

Comment: Your output is 3:30. In military time, that is 0330.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033889/convert-army-time-to-regular-time-am-pm-in-php --- http://style-vs-substance.com/programming/convert-24-hour-military-time-to-12-hour-ampm-time-in-php/

Comment: Input is military (2200) `(out + 2400 - in) % 2400`

Comment: What do you mean by "military" time? People seem to be confused here. Is the expected output to be as you state `3:30`, or `0330`? 0330 when literally spoken is just that "oh three hundred", but "three thirty" is another animal. What is the source of the data also?

Comment: Funk Forty Niner sorry my bad i mean 24 hour format i just want to calculate the late of these two. So i put an expected output.

Comment: If you had the date with the time it would be easy

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your times are strings in the form HH:mm, this will work:

```
$in = new DateTime('22:00');
$out = new DateTime('01:30');
// if in is > out, assume out is on the next day
if ($in > $out) $out->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$diff = $out->diff($in);
echo $diff->format('%H:%i');
```