# Calculate minutes in a date interval AM minutes PM minutes in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

Is there any build in function in PHP that can calculate the amount on minutes of AM and PM time in a date-time interval (working with 24h format). Lets say we have:

```
$start_date = '2021-03-30 11:30:00';
$end_date = '2021-03-30 12:30:00';
```

So it will output:

```
$AM = 30;
$PM = 30;
```

Another example:

```
$start_date = '2021-03-30 10:00:00';
$end_date = '2021-03-30 13:30:00';
```

Should output:

```
$AM = 120;
$PM = 90;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert the time from AM/PM to 24 hour format in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955209/how-to-convert-the-time-from-am-pm-to-24-hour-format-in-php)

Comment: @Gabriel no, because I'm not looking to convert the dates, I just need a date-time diff split in AM (in minutes) and PM (in minutes).

Comment: look into Carbon (https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: @bt19 Will the start date and end date be on the same day? If not, how will the output look like?

Comment: @Gabriel No need to install packages for simple tasks.

Comment: did you find the solution? which never fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects from those date strings and manually create a `mid_noon` variable datetime object. Find the difference of both objects with `mid_noon` using `DateTime::diff` and calculate the time of difference in minutes like below:

```
<?php

$start_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s','2021-03-30 10:00:00');
$end_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s','2021-03-30 13:30:00');

$mid_noon = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$start_date->format('Y-m-d'). ' 12:00:00');

$start_diff = $mid_noon->diff($start_date);
$end_diff = $end_date->diff($mid_noon);

$am = $start_diff->h * 60 + $start_diff->i;
$pm = $end_diff->h * 60 + $end_diff->i;

echo $am," ",$pm;
```

Comment: @bt19 Just a note: Above solution assumes that one date is before or equal to noon and the other one is after or equal to noon.  I hope I am not speculating.

Comment: hi @nice_dev in my case my shift starts 6pm to 2am but your code counts correct from 6pm to 12 am but it fails after 12 do u have any solution?

Comment: @HamzaQureshi Can you post this as a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Solution with strtotime and some elementary school math.

```
$am = intdiv(43200 - strtotime('2021-03-30 10:00:00')%86400,60);
$pm = intdiv(strtotime('2021-03-30 13:30:00')%86400 - 43200,60);
```

strtotime provides the seconds since 01/01/1970. With seconds%86400 we get the seconds from midnight. 86400 are the seconds of a whole day. 43200 is the seconds of half a day or 12:00. The differences 43200 - secondsStart and secondsEnd - 43200 give us the seconds for AM and PM. We only have to divide this by 60 to get the minutes.

The following variant with the [DateTime extension dt](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt) is easier to understand.

Given:

```
$start_date = '2021-03-30 10:00:00';
$end_date = '2021-03-30 13:30:00';
```

Calculation:

```
$day12h = dt::create($start_date)->setTime('12:00');

$am = dt::create($start_date)->diffTotal($day12h,'Minutes');
$pm = $day12h->diffTotal($end_date,'Minutes');
```

Comment: what about in my case my shift starts 6pm to 2am but your code counts correct from 6pm to 12 am but it fails after 12am to 2am do u have any solution?