# How do I convert date/time from 24-hour format to 12-hour AM/PM?

Tags: php, date

From a data feed I'm getting date and time in this format:

```
19:24:15 06/13/2013
```

I need to have it converted to be in 12-hour AM/PM without the seconds. So the above time would be 7:24 PM. The date should remain in mm/dd/yyyy format. Is there an elegant way to do this in PHP (not MySQL)? Thanks!

Comment: That's MySQL, this is PHP.

Comment: Read the accepted answer.  If you look at the applicable documentation, you'll see it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Not duplicate of: 'Convert date from YYYYMMDD to DD/MM/YYYY format in PHP'.

Comment: Proper duplicate: [How to get Am/ PM from a datetime in php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3404699/55075).

Comment: Actually this one: [How to convert the time from AM/PM to 24 hour format in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16955209/55075)

Comment: $time='16:00';
 echo date('h:i:s a ', strtotime($time));

Answer (score 151, accepted):

I think you can use [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/it/function.date.php) function to achive this

```
$date = '19:24:15 06/13/2013'; 
echo date('h:i:s a m/d/Y', strtotime($date));
```

This will output

```
07:24:15 pm 06/13/2013
```

#### [Live Sample](http://ideone.com/VURw6D)

> **h** is used for 12 digit time
>   **i** stands for minutes
>   **s** seconds
>   **a** will return am or pm (use in uppercase for AM PM)
>   **m** is used for months with digits
>   **d** is used for days in digit
>   **Y** uppercase is used for 4 digit year (use it lowercase for two digit)

Updated

This is with [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/it/datetime.format.php)

```
$date = new DateTime('19:24:15 06/13/2013');
echo $date->format('h:i:s a m/d/Y') ;
```

#### [Live Sample](http://ideone.com/XdX9oL)

Comment: How do you make the hour single digit, so '09' is '9'? Thanks!

Comment: I just found it, 'g' is for without leading zeros on the hour.

Answer (score 15):

You can use date function to format it by using the code below:

```
echo date("g:i a", strtotime("13:30:30 UTC"));
```

**output: 1:30 pm**

Answer (score 14):

Use smaller `h`

```php
# 24 hrs 
H:i 
// output 14:20

# 12 hrs 
h:i 
// output 2:20
```