# date_create_from_format is returning wrong day

Tags: php, date

I am currently facing an issue with date_create_from_format PHP.
Here is the code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kathmandu');
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:iA', '28/05/2016 15:24PM');
echo date('d/m/Y h:iA',$date->getTimestamp());
//returns 29/05/2016 03:24AM
```

I am just trying to change the 24 hour time to 12 hour. But now working.Thanks.

Comment: try setting timezone...

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kathmandu');

Comment: timezone is already there. Let me edit the question with timezone.
timezone doesn't change anything.

Comment: could it be that `15:24` + `PM` won't work? either, or I guess.

Comment: This will help you, http://stackoverflow.com/a/17098203/2210140

Comment: @Jeff What can I do then? Can you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: @BulletProof47 follow the answer Keyur posted!

Comment: Oh thanks. I removed AM PM from the string, now its working. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You must create date from one type. Use **PM-AM** OR **24h format**.
Otherwise it will be 15:43 PM = 12:43 PM + 3 hour.

Try like this:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i', '28/05/2016 15:24');
```

**UPDATE**

If you do not control the input data, you can use a crutch:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i', substr('28/05/2016 15:24PM', 0, -2));
```

Comment: You have '28/05/2016 15:24PM' string in DB?

Comment: Yes but from another API URL.Not that I can control.

Comment: This is bad, since 15:43 PM = 12:43 PM + 3 hour. Can use a crutch:
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i', str_replace(['PM', 'AM'], '', '28/05/2016 15:24PM')); OR 
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i', substr('28/05/2016 15:24PM', 0, -2));

Comment: Oh thanks. I removed AM PM from the string, now its working. Thanks guys.