# How can I display current time in HTML input type 'time'?

Tags: php, html, datetime

I have tried it using PHP's 'time()' function but I am not getting my desired result on the frontend. Here is the line of code:

```html
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="select-time" value="<?php echo date('h:i A',time()); ?>" name="time" required>
```

Here is what it shows on the frontend:
[image]

Comment: So what is your desired result on the front end, and what are yo actually seeing on the front end

Comment: **NOTE** the `time()` in `date('h:i A',time());` is irrelevant. If left out it will do exactly that by default

Comment: what are you seeing and what do you want to see?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I want the current time picked and shown in the input field on the frontend just as the page loads.

Comment: @RiggsFolly-- yes I expected the same, but nothing shows up except the default format '--:-- --'

Comment: That is because you are setting it in a wrong format. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#time_value_format

Comment: Use `H` (capital letter). This outputs 24hr format and you will get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the format the `date` variable is printing out is valid for the HTML input you want to use.

If it is not (which is what I believe the issue is), then you will need to modify your `date/time` variable so that it prints in the correct format.

From the picture it looks like you simply want `Hours:Minutes Seconds`. Is this correct to assume?

```
<?php
//Optional if you wish to set your timezone
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
 
// This would print the format 2021-09-07 11:04:48   
echo date("Y-m-d,h:m:s");

//You probably want to adjust it to something like this
echo date("h:m s");
?>
```

So to answer your question: Replace your PHP code ( <strike>`<?php echo date('h:i A',time()); ?>`</strike> ) with this, and it should be in the correct format.
`<?php echo date("h:m s); ?>`

Comment: Please mark this as the solution if you find it to have helped otherwise if you are still having problems with this, please leave a comment with more info about what is going wrong and I will attempt to help you. :)

Answer (score 2):

A valid date-time as defined in RFC 3339 with these additional qualifications:

the literal letters T and Z in the date/time syntax must always be uppercase
the date-fullyear production is instead defined as four or more digits representing a number greater than 0
Examples

1990-12-31T23:59:60Z
1996-12-19T16:39:57-08:00

Solution

To create RFC 3339 format in PHP you can use:

```
echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', $row['Time']);
```

or in another way:

```
echo date("c", strtotime($row['Time']));
```

or if you prefer objective style:

```
echo (new DateTime($row['Time']))->format('c');

<input type="datetime-local"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', $row['Time']); ?>" class="date" name="start" REQUIRED>
```

Use links for more info

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 1):

if in database time stored like this "20:18" Simply Do the

```
<input type="time" class="form-control" name="activity_time" placeholder="Activity Time" value="<?php echo date('h:i') ?>" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

@RiggsFolly is correct, the input time from the database is irrelevant because the `date()` function is to convert the string to date + format the output.

Let's say the current time is 7:30 pm (night)

### Using h:i A (doesn't work ✘)

**PHP echo**
Because you specified `AM` it is showing the AM in the output

```php
$t = date('h:i A');
echo $t;
// output: 7:30 pm
```

**HTML `date` input**
The same `AM` will not work inside the date input

```html
<input type="time" value="<?php echo date('h:i A') ?>">
<!-- output: --:-- -- -->
```

### Using h:i (doesn't work ✘)

**PHP echo**
How about we use without `AM` or `PM`. just plain time not provide the `AM` `PM`. Probably if you are following 24hrs format then you can consider this as AM

```php
$t = date('h:i');
echo $t;
// 7:30
```

**HTML `date` input**

```html
<input type="time" value="<?php echo date('h:i') ?>">
<!-- output: 07:30 AM (the AM and PM doesn't work here, the reason why it displays AM is because that is the first thing in the date dropdown list) -->
```

### H:i (works ✔)

**PHP echo**
You can try the `H`. This is for 24hr format.

```php
$t = date('H:i');
echo $t;
// 19:30
```

**HTML `date` input**
No need to specify the `A`, since it is 24hrs format, the input automatically detects and displays the correct time.

```html
<input type="time" value="<?php echo date('H:i') ?>">
<!-- output: 7:30 pm -->
```

Here's a simple explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51515814/5413283