# How to format date time and morning or evening

Tags: php

I have a problem on formatting the year month and date hours minutes and AM or pm how can I format this?

```
yyyy, mm, dd, hh: mm pm
```

`2014-02-03 13:54:49` but I cant get the `AM` and `PM`

Comment: show the code you have done for this..is it a timestamp date or unix timestamp

Comment: Manuals are excellent sources of information if you bother to read them. http://PHP.net/date

Comment: You may want to check this thread --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404699/how-to-get-am-pm-from-a-datetime-in-php =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php 
echo date('Y, M, d, H:i a');
?>
```

Lot more info here: http://php.net/date

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> echo date('Y-m-d, H:i A');